# Finding eigenvectors for the largest eigenvalue vs one with the largest absolute value

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If I want to solve a generalized eigenvalue problem such as:

$$A x = \lambda x$$

The problem is to find eigenvectors corresponding to the largest eigenvalues (sometimes in an optimization problem that form it as a generalized eigenvalue problem).

I notice some people solve this problem by finding eigenvectors corresponding to the largest eigenvalues **in absolute value**.

Are these two method similar? What are the difference between them? I mean in what situation I should use eigenvalues in absolute value?

Comment: Could you provide some links with methods you say? I cannot help but I'm interested in methods providing eigenvectors corresponding to the maximum absolute value of eigenvalue. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have links actually. I am trying to solve the generalized eigenvalue problem and not sure which one should I use and what is the difference.

Comment: Thanks fir the response, @Matthew!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finding the eigenvector with the *largest magnitude* eigenvalue is the easiest and cheapest, since you can use power iteration directly. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration

If you need to find the eigenvector with *largest* eigenvalue, you must modify the procedure. Sometimes you know that the largest eigenvalue is also the largest-magnitude eigenvalue (for example, if your matrix is positive-definite) and so you can again use power iteration. Otherwise, you can find the largest-magnitude eigenvalue; if it is positive, you are done. Otherwise, construct a new *spectrally-shifted* matrix $M' = M - \lambda I$ where $\lambda$ is the largest-magnitude, negative, eigenvalue. The eigenvalues of $M'$ are now all non-negative, so find its largest-magnitude eigenvalue $\mu$ and corresponding eigenvector $v$; the largest eigenvalue of $M$ is then $\mu+\lambda$ with eigenvector $v$.

As for when to calculate one versus the other -- that's application-dependent. If you tell us what you need the eigenvector for, we might be able to give you advice.

Comment: Thank you so much. My application is try to solve the optimization problem something like argmax_{T}(trace(T*A*T)/trace(T*B*T)) (A and B are some forms of matrices) and this problem can be approximated using a generalized eigenvalue problem. A*B^{-1} * x = lambda * x. So the T will be the eigenvectors corresponding to the largest eigenvalues such as T = [v1, v2, ...]. The number of eigenvectors can be input parameter that we can set. I am not sure if I describe the problem explicitely.

Comment: On my behalf, thanks a lot,as well @user7530!